# Why does sencha build app fail?

Tags: build, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm allways running into this exception when I try to build my app with the sencha commandline tools. However, other apps seem to work fine. What am I missing?

[image]

**UPDATE**

I figured out it has something to do with the fact that I want my buildPath to be outside of the app directory. My section in the app.json looks like this:

```
"buildPaths": {
    "production": "../deploy/frontenddemo/production",
    "testing": "../deploy/frontenddemo/testing",
    "package": "../deploy/frontenddemo/package",
    "native": "../deploy/frontenddemo/native"
},
```

If I change it to:

```
"buildPaths": {
    "production": "build/production",
    ...
},
```

Everything works as expected. I don't know why. It should be possible to have the builds outside the app directory I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of try and error. I found the root cause of this issue.

My app.json looked like this:

```
"archivePath": "../deploy/frontenddemo/archive/",
"buildPaths": {
    "testing": "../deploy/frontenddemo/testing",
    "production": "../deploy/frontenddemo/production",
    "package": "../deploy/frontenddemo/package",
    "native": "../deploy/frontenddemo/native"
},
```

The problem with this structure is that both archive and builds produce a directory "sencha" outside of the configured path. Meaning they both create `../deploy/frontenddemo/sencha`
with different contents. I wonder if that is documented somewhere?

The fix was easy. I just changed the paths to this:

```
"archivePath": "../deploy/frontenddemo/archive/",
"buildPaths": {
    "testing": "../deploy/frontenddemo/builds/testing",
    "production": "../deploy/frontenddemo/builds/production",
    "package": "../deploy/frontenddemo/builds/package",
    "native": "../deploy/frontenddemo/builds/native"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had previous issues deploying directly to a web server such as MAMP, or even Mac's default web server, in ~/Sites/

Have you tried changing your deployment directory to something other then MAMP, and then manually copy/paste it over?

Also, what exact version of the SDK are you using? 2.1 beta 3 was released a bit ago, as well as a new Sencha Cmd 3.0.0.122 (used to be called Sencha SDK Tools).

Forum Announcement: [Sencha Touch 2.1.0 Beta 3 is available](http://www.sencha.com/forum/announcement.php?f=91&a=36)

Comment: I moved all my stuff to `~/Documents/` and tried again - no luck, same error. Then I upgraded to the latest Sencha Cmd 3.0.0.122 but this was giving me other errors and it seems this version is only for ST 2.1 projects, right? I'm still on ST 2.0.